# How can I tell if the current process is a service or not (C++, Win32)?

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I tell if the application my code is running in, is it in a service or an application? Why do I want to know this - I'm writing some code that is injected into the target application and that code has no way of knowing this information up front, so it has to work it out itself.

I cannot rely on any code being called from the service control manager, start, stop, or command line parameters.

I'm currently looking at `GetConsoleWindow()` which I hope will return `NULL` for a service (no console) and a window handle for any application (has a console). Not sure how valid this assumption is.

Any ideas for a better solution?

Comment: What's the reason your code needs to tell? You'll probably be able to detect that thing explicitly. For example, if you only want to affect the user's interactive desktop (or desktops on Terminal Server), or if you don't want to run within the SYSTEM account (or some other service account), you can detect those things...

Comment: How do you define a service (as far as the OS is concerned an APP is just an APP). How you define a service will indicate how we can detect it.

Comment: I'd imagine a service is "anything listed in the `services.msc` control panel. ;)

Comment: The reason I want to know if it is a service is because from the point of view of the tools I am writing (which can end up running inside a service or an application) there is a difference. Often the service will be on a restricted account (IIS), plus startup/shutdown issues are different for services compared to applications.

Comment: Martin, a service is not the same as an application. You only have to write one to know they are very different beasts. Yes you can typically write a service that can run as an app, but that isn't what I'm doing. My code may end up running inside a service or inside an app and I need to know which in order to take slightly different choices for the case when it is a service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search the current process id (`GetCurrentProcessId`) from the list of all running services (`EnumServicesStatusEx`)?

Comment: I didn't know about EnumServiceStatus(Ex). Thanks. Looks like just the right approach.

Comment: Will every application have permission to do that?

Comment: @Yetti99 read the documentation, there are permissions involved that *could* prevent the enumeration from running, or omit individual services from being reported.

Comment: @RemyLebeau read the docs, are you crazy ;)  I see EnumServicesStatusEx() might return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED "when The handle does not have the SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE access right".   So if the current process doesn't have permission to enumerate the services then this method to determine if the current process is a service or not won't work, it seems.

Comment: @Yetti99 keep reading, the doc also says: "*If the caller does not have the SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS access right to a service, the service is silently omitted from the list of services returned to the client.*" That said, if your code runs under a user account with sufficient rights, then `EnumServiceStatusEx()` should work fine for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption of GetConsoleWindow() is not valid.

It seems to me that you care about the context of your process more.  Are you asking that if your program is running in service context or the user session?  If so, use ProcessIdToSessionId() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990%28v=VS.85%29.aspx to get your session id and you will know it.

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI to query for [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instances where 'ProcessId=MyProcessid'.  If there is no match, then your process is not a service.

Background on WMI app creation in C++ [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Vista or later you can check the session id. Session 0 is reserved for services and non-interactive programs. User sessions start from 1.

Answer (score -2):

Use OpenProcessToken to get the current process token.  Then use CheckTokenMembership to see if the token includes the WinServiceSid well-known SID.

Comment: Not every service process has that SID!