# Is it possible to programmatically determine if my app is running as a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell if the current process is a service or not (C++, Win32)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625270/how-can-i-tell-if-the-current-process-is-a-service-or-not-c-win32)

How can I programmically determine whether my app is running as a Windows Service application?

I guess there is a way of calling the `GetUserNameA` function and check the retrieved name matches either "SYSTEM", "LOCAL SERVICE", or "NETWORK SERVICE". But I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Might want to tell us more about your problem (at least what language you're coding in).

Comment: How would you not know? If you wrote the application as a Windows Service, chances are that's how it's running. If *not*, you also have a pretty good idea it didn't suddenly become one.