# How do i check if an application is running as a process or a service in windows using c++?

Tags: c++, windows

I have this requirement while using [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), which returns Windows Services as well as Processes. 
Is there a way to differentiate between them, provided I have the process handle and process id.

Comment: [winapi - How can I tell if the current process is a service or not (C++, Win32)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625270/how-can-i-tell-if-the-current-process-is-a-service-or-not-c-win32)

Comment: Windows services _are_ processes. What's your real requirement?

Answer (score 0):

For windows services, you can use "sc" command to start, stop or query the status of services.
For windows processes, you can use "tasklist" command to query the status of programs.